# Hive fails to deserialize optional thrift fields

Tags: hive, thrift

When I create a table like

```
create table myTable
  row format serde "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.thrift.ThriftDeserializer"
  with serdeproperties ("serialization.class"="com.myco.MyClass",
         "serialization.format"="org.apache.thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol") 
  stored as SEQUENCEFILE;
```

this works fine for thrift structures with required fields like

```
struct MyClass {
    1:  required i32 foo;
}
```

but structs with optional fields like

```
struct MyClass2 {
    1:  optional i32 foo;
}
```

give the following error

```
FAILED: SemanticException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: name expected at the position 11 of 'int:struct<>' but '>' is found.
```

Since Hive allows `NULL` values for columns, there is an obvious mapping of the optional construct.

How do I make Hive deserialize thrift classes containing optional fields?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: After throwing "SemanticException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: name expected at" into google I got a number of similar problems. Seems to be a Hive SerDe issue. Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137194/hive-udf-text-to-array) post?

Comment: Thanks, JensG. That error seems to occur in pretty diverse situations. Do you have any idea what triggers it?

Comment: This is a hive bug, when you use higher thrift version such as 0.9 to generate thrift java files, it will generate a no-static private field called "optionals", which won't be ignored and will be treated as normal field by the ObjectInspector.

Answer (score 0):

Which Thrift version are you compiliing your thrift file with? I'm on Hive 12 and I had this exact error with thrift on 0.9.X. I downgraded my thrift version to 0.7.0 and it works fine with Hive 12.

If you're stuck with the current Hive version, downgrade your Thrift version when generating the Thrift Java files. The ThriftDeserializer in Hive doesn't ignore certain fields in that it is supposed to and creates optional empty structs, which Hive can't handle.

Based off of the Hive version you are on, check https://github.com/apache/hive/releases and see which Thrift version they used for the release and use that Thrift version to compile your thrift schema to java.

Comment: This is not an answer, should have been a comment.