# Create a sequence array from a given start and end date in HIVE

Tags: arrays, date, hadoop, hive

I have a data table with id, start, and end as columns, like:

> id  |  start    |   end
>
> 1  |  2011-01-01 |  2011-01-03
>
> 2  |  2011-02-13 |  2011-02-14

what I want to do in HIVE is to add the whole range of days as an array in a separate column, so I want to obtain:

> id  |  start    |   end    |     range
>
> 1  |  2011-01-01 |  2011-01-03 |
>   ['2011-01-01','2011-01-02','2011-01-03']
>
> 2  |  2011-02-13 |  2011-02-14 | ['2011-02-13','2011-02-14']

I tried to use collect_set() but could not get it working. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are the range of days in your dataset or do you need to generate them based on `start` and `end` ?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 I need to generate them first based on start and end, and then insert them in a new column.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will need to create a custom UDF to do that, which isn't too difficult if you have some basic Java knowledge. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21197354/88839 that demonstrates how to return an array from a UDF. I have not tested it, but if I get some time later I might give it a go.

Here are also some instructions on creating a UDF without Maven, but its probably easier with Maven - http://appsintheopen.com/posts/29-creating-a-basic-hive-udf